# Can't jailbreak iPod touch 4g (ios 4.3.3) on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I am running XP as a virtual machine on Ubuntu. I can sync and restore my iPod Touch 4G using the virtual machine, but I can't jailbreak it; because after I put the device on DFU mode, Windows does not recognize it.

It cannot find the driver – or the driver that is installed is not correct, because in the device manager I see an exclamation mark next to the device.

I searched for the problem, and apparently the only solution is to remove and reinstall iTunes and all other Apple software. So, I did that. It can still sync and restore, but when the device is in DFU mode, it is still not recognized. Since it is not recognized in DFU mode, I can't start the jailbreaking operation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found an iMac in library and did the jailbreaking with that. But I am still looking for a solution to the problem for my future jailbreaking sessions. So, please let me know about your ideas.

Comment: Can I ask what OS your host is and also what VM software are you running, VBox, Vmware etc?

Comment: Host is Ubuntu  11.04. I'm using Virtualbox version 4.0.4.

Comment: Honestly I would use VMWare Workstation, personal preference and I've found it works with iPhone a lot better. You could also try installing Windows 7 in the VM instead rather than XP.

Comment: I can give VMWare a try. Installing Windows 7 on my computer as a virtual machine is not a good idea since I am using a 6.5 year old notebook. I installed Windows 7 once (not as a virtual machine, as dualboot) and it kept freezing because the CPU couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to dual boot with Windows 7 (Newer Drivers will be on there for iPods) and run it through there.

Comment: I really don't want to do that because my intention is to get rid of Windows completely. I am only using it to sync my ipod and manage my music collection. That's why I went from dualboot to virtual machine a week ago.